# GNOME Sushi preview not working for video files

Tags: gnome, gstreamer, previews, gnome-sushi

I have GNOME-sushi installed on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Initially when I selected a video and pressed <kbd>spacebar</kbd>, the following error occurred.

[image]

After installing the `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad` and `gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly` packages, only the audio is played but not the video.

The following are already installed (used `dpkg -l | grep gstreamer`)

```
ii  gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0:amd64                 1.16.2-2                              amd64        GObject introspection data for the GStreamer library
ii  gstreamer1.0-alsa:amd64                    1.16.2-4                              amd64        GStreamer plugin for ALSA
ii  gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0:amd64             3.0.27-1                              amd64        Clutter PLugin for GStreamer 1.0
ii  gstreamer1.0-gl:amd64                      1.16.2-4                              amd64        GStreamer plugins for GL
ii  gstreamer1.0-gtk3:amd64                    1.16.2-1ubuntu2                       amd64        GStreamer plugin for GTK+3
ii  gstreamer1.0-packagekit                    1.1.13-2ubuntu1                       amd64        GStreamer plugin to install codecs using PackageKit
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:amd64             1.16.2-2.1ubuntu1                     amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "bad" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:amd64            1.16.2-4                              amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "base" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps             1.16.2-4                              amd64        GStreamer helper programs from the "base" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:amd64            1.16.2-1ubuntu2                       amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "good" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly:amd64            1.16.2-2build1                        amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "ugly" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio:amd64              1.16.2-1ubuntu2                       amd64        GStreamer plugin for PulseAudio
ii  gstreamer1.0-tools                         1.16.2-2                              amd64        Tools for use with GStreamer
ii  gstreamer1.0-x:amd64                       1.16.2-4                              amd64        GStreamer plugins for X11 and Pango
ii  libgstreamer-gl1.0-0:amd64                 1.16.2-4                              amd64        GStreamer GL libraries
ii  libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0:amd64        1.16.2-2.1ubuntu1                     amd64        GStreamer libraries from the "bad" set
ii  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:amd64       1.16.2-4                              amd64        GStreamer libraries from the "base" set
ii  libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:amd64       1.16.2-1ubuntu2                       amd64        GStreamer development files for libraries from the "good" set
ii  libgstreamer1.0-0:amd64                    1.16.2-2                              amd64        Core GStreamer libraries and elements
```

How to install the missing plugins?

Comment: I thought it was not working but now I see that some files work and other not... cant tell why yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install 3 packages by the command below:

```
apt-get install -y gstreamer1.0-gtk3 gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio gstreamer1.0-libav
```

It works for me on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Works also on Ubuntu 22.04. Thank You!